# Spring boot JPA Schema issue in @Query annotation

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i'm creating a microservice that connects to a postgresql DB, and i want to execute a custom query, the thing is when i test it, it throws the following error:

[image]

when i execute the query in DBeaver, it throws the same error

[image]

but if i add double quotes to the schema, then it works

[image]

This is the function with the custom query

[image]

How can i add those double quotes to the schema in the @Query annotation?

my application.properties looks like this

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/user_config
server.port=8079
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=SSFF
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Comment: Why a native query? Why not a JPQL which takes care of al that/

Comment: Have you tried to add the double quote in your @query?

Comment: @M.Deinum and how would my Query look with this method?

Comment: @ThomasPoignant yes, i did ("select c from {\"h-schema\"}users c where c.user like %?1%") but it throws syntax error

Comment: You could write a query method `findByUserLike(String chars)` which would generate a query or if you really want a JPQL something like `SELECT U FROM User U WHERE U.user like %:chars%`. You have an entity with mapping, use that to your advantage.